# What is the relationship between covariance and correlation coefficient in the equation?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, descriptive-statistics

I want to know about **covariance** and **correlation coefficient**.

What is their relationship in terms of equation?
What are their similarities and differences?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Have you read the equation for correlation?

Comment: How in the world does this need more clarification? It's as specific as it can get.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sigma_X$ and $\sigma_Y$ be the standard deviations of two random variables, $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Then the (Pearson) correlation between $X$ and $Y$, denoted $\rho(X,Y)$, is defined as:

$$
\rho(X,Y)=\dfrac{
cov(X,Y)
}{
\sigma_X\sigma_Y
}
$$

In words, correlation is the covariance scales by the product of the standard deviations.

Another way to think of correlation is as the covariance between two variables after the variables are scaled to have have unit variance by dividing each by its corresponding standard deviation.

$$
cov(X/\sigma_X,Y/\sigma_Y)=\dfrac{1}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}cov(X,Y)\\=\rho(X,Y)
$$

In general, $cov(aX,Y)=a\times cov(X,Y)$ and $cov(X,bY)=b\times cov(X,Y)$, by the linearity of the expected value definition of covariance, explaining how the division by the standard deviations can be pulled out of the covariance.

$$
cov(X,Y)=\mathbb E\left[
(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)
\right]
$$